# The playback engine could not find the binaries required to run cross browser coded UI test..." shows

Tags: selenium, coded-ui-tests

After installing Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing, and try to run test case on chrome, "System.Exception: The playback engine could not find the binaries required to run cross browser coded UI tests. This may be because the Selenium .NET bindings and Selenium Chrome driver are not installed or an older version of the Selenium Components Installer was used. For more information about installing the binaries, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=267598" occurs. Can anyone help to resolve the issue? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when the cross browser plugin has not installed correctly.

These are the manual steps to install the driver.

1. Download chrome driver from:
   http://chromedriver.googlecode.com/files/
2. Download selenium dot net bindings from:
   http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/
3. Right click on the downloaded zip files.
4. Select "properties".
5. Under "General" tab, click on the "Unblock" button.
6. Now unzip both the files and copy the contents to the following path (for the selenium-dotnet 2.29.1 binaries, copy the contents of net40 folder):
   "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components" (for 32 bit machines)

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components" (for 64 bit machines)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! While the link may contain the answer to the question, we'd like to see the actual answer to the question on the post. Can you update it, please?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Install Selenium components**

On the Extensions menu, choose Manage Extensions.

In the Manage Extensions dialog box, search for Selenium components for Cross Browser Testing.

Highlight the extension and choose Download.